# Robo Copy a File From a Network Drive to a Remote Destination Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, robocopy, network-drive

I am attempting to copy a file from my network drive to all computers on my network but i am running into a few issues. First thing is that im getting this warning:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Started : Tuesday, June 30, 2020 9:33:31 AM
2020/06/30 09:33:33 ERROR 67 (0x00000043) Getting File System Type of Source \\108wg-fs-05\03 - 
Section Folders\04 - SCM\4 - Backups" UserProfileBackup.ps1 \C$\Users\Public\Desktop \r:1 \w:0\
The network name cannot be found.

Source = \\108wg-fs-05\03 - Section Folders\04 - SCM\4 - Backups" UserProfileBackup.ps1 
\C$\Users\Public\Desktop \r:1 \w:0\
 Dest -

Files : *.*

Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : No Destination Directory Specified.

   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?


****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

these are the 2 codes im working with
this one is meant to copy a startup script to the computers on the network that connects each to the share drive

```
robocopy "\\108wg-fs-05\03 - Section Folders\04 - SCM\scripts\startupscript.vbs" "\\$cheese\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /r:1 /w:0
```

This one is meant to back up user data

```
robocopy "\\108wg-fs-05\03 - Section Folders\04 - SCM\4 - Backups\UserProfileBackup.ps1" "\\$cheese\C$\Users\Public\Desktop" /r:1 /w:0
```

My goal is to get each to beable to pull their respective files from the network drive and both give me the same error. Any fixes?

Comment: what is the name of the server share that you are trying to access? your command uses `03 - Section Folders` and that is a rather odd share name ... [*grin*] you can get the share names thus >>> `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Share -ComputerName $TargetComputerName` <<<

Comment: Are you starting robocopy via powershell? Robocopy is tricky to start via powershell. And robocopy is designed copy directories, not single files. For single files copy-item should be better

Comment: i guess it doesnt need to be a robocopy, im just modifying old code to become more flexible. idk but maybe a simple copy would work better?\

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

1. You have given Robocopy SOURCE: <a file>
2. You have not separated your inputs to SOURCE: ... so it is seeing both <src> and <dest> in SOURCE with DESTINATION blank
3. Robocopy likes single quoted <src> and <dest>

Calling Robocopy within powershell, you need to modify the source + destination to folders only and use single quotes to separate the arguments.

Example below copies 1x file. Alter $src_file to "*.*" for the whole folder

```
$src = 'C:\LocalPC\FolderWithFile2Sync\coolFile2Sync.csv'
$dest = '\\10.1.1.x\DestFolder\FolderForSyncdFiles'

$dest_dir = (Split-Path $dest.Replace("""","'") -Parent)
$src_dir  = (Split-Path $src.Replace("""","'")  -Parent)
$src_file = (Split-Path $src.Replace("""","'")  -Leaf -Resolve)

robocopy.exe "$src_dir" "$dest_dir" "$src_file" /IS /IT /IM /TBD /MT:1 /R:5 /W:5 /V /NP /LOG+:'C:\LocalPC\log.txt'

#/R:5  — Retry 5 times (you can set various number, default is 1 million).
#/W:5  — Wait for a few seconds before retrying (you can also set another number, the default is 30 seconds).
#/TBD  — Wait for share names To Be Defined (retry error 67).
#/MT:1 — Do multi-threaded copies with n threads (default is 8).

#/IS :: Include Same files.
#/IT :: Include Tweaked files.    
#/IM :: Include Modified files (Includes same files with different times).

#/NP   — No Progress – can’t show percentage copied.
#/V    — Generates verbose output, displaying skipped files.
```